# Login with facebook is not working properly

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am using facebook api for using login functionality of facebook on my website. But there is a problem with it, it does not redirected to my website after login. It redirects to facebook home page. I don't know why it happens. My code is below:

This file name is logign_facebook.php

```
<?php

require 'facebook/facebook.php';
require 'config/fbconfig.php';
require 'config/functions.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'app_id' => APP_ID,
            'app_seceret' => APP_SECRET,
            ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }

    if (!empty($user_profile )) {
        # User info ok? Let's print it (Here we will be adding the login and registering routines)

        $username = $user_profile['name'];
             $uid = $user_profile['id'];
         $email = $user_profile['email'];
        $user = new User();
        $userdata = $user->checkUser($uid, 'facebook', $username,$email,$twitter_otoken,$twitter_otoken_secret);
        if(!empty($userdata)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id'] = $userdata['id'];
 $_SESSION['oauth_id'] = $uid;

            $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['username'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = $userdata['oauth_provider'];
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
    } else {
        # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
        die("There was an error.");
    }
} else {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array( 'scope' => 'email'));
    header("Location: " . $login_url);
}
?>
```

Please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook needs to know the URL to redirect back to when the user has logged in.

You can pass this through the the **getLoginUrl()** function in the PHP SDK as below:

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://yoururlhere.com/logign_facebook.php',
    'scope'        => array('email')
));
```

A full list of parameters for this function can be seen at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Apps>>[app_name]>>basic

And scroll down  to the "Website with Facebook Login"

Enter your desired URL in the textfield.